# <fieldset> doesn't adapt width of <form> when containing <pre> code

Tags: html, css, width, overflow, fieldset

I have the following code.

```css
form {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  /* why doesn't it hold? */
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
code {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="container">
    <code>
&lt;some&gt;
 &lt;very&gt;
  &lt;looooooooooooooooooooooooong&gt;
   &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;code&gt;
   &lt;here which=&quot;should break in multiple lines, or be scrollable&quot;&gt;
    </code>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The problem is, that the `<fieldset>` seems to adapt the width from the `<code>` element inside, instead of the outer `<form>`. The green box should be contained inside the blue box, and the code should be scrollable.

But instead, the green box blasts out of the blue box:

[image]

---

**How can I make the `<code>` adapt the width from the `<fieldset>` which should adapt its width from the `<form>`?**

Comment: It works fine when leaving out the `<fieldset>` - but I need to keep it, so there must be a way to style the `<fieldset>` in a way it works also?

Comment: The screenshot above was taken with Chrome. Firefox renders it slightly different: it draws the blue box around the wide green box (ignoring the width of the `<form>` completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `min-width:0` of the `<fieldset>` does the trick. 
Got the idea from [<fieldset> resizes wrong; appears to have unremovable `min-width: min-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408815/fieldset-resizes-wrong-appears-to-have-unremovable-min-width-min-content?rq=1)

```css
form {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  /* why doesn't it hold? */
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
code {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre;
}
/* This does the trick */

fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="container">
    <code>
&lt;some&gt;
 &lt;very&gt;
  &lt;looooooooooooooooooooooooong&gt;
   &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;code&gt;
   &lt;here which=&quot;should break in multiple lines, or be scrollable&quot;&gt;
    </code>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```