# Prevent child from increasing width of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a very wide `table` inside a `div`, which in turn is inside a `fieldset` which is inside a `form` which is inside an `article`.

This wide table results in the `div` and the `fieldset` to increase their width. The `form` does not increase the width.

I want to show a horizontal scrollbar for the `div`. But this doesn't work, because it has the same width as the `table`.

How can I prevent the `div` from increasing its width?
Please know that the height of the `table` is dynamic and changes based on user interactions.
I would like to achieve this without JS.

[Fiddle demonstrating my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/k4y332f5/).

If you think this is a duplicate to an existing question, please test the solution first with my specific setup, thanks. I tested quite a few and none seemed to work in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a deeper look, I noticed that the `fieldset` element has a `min-width` attribute inherited directly from the web-kit (at least in Chrome). It appears that it goes against what you want to do.

You can solve your issue by specifying for the `fieldset` element:

**CSS**

```
fieldset { min-width:0px; }
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/12u1o5e3/)

---

*UPDATE*: A fix that also works for Firefox

From an explanation of the `fieldset` behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408815/fieldset-resizes-wrong-appears-to-have-unremovable-min-width-min-content#answer-17863685) (thanks @Pangloss for catching this!):

**CSS**

```
fieldset {
    min-width: 0px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    fieldset {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

New [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rcanyhm/)

Comment: It does work for Webkit but does not work for Firefox.

Comment: @Pangloss Thanks, I will check for that an edit my answer.

Comment: Very interesting indeed, tried all but Firefox just doesn't like it.

Comment: For IE it also works. Is this a bug in Firefox?

Comment: I doubt it, those replaced elements just hard for styling.

Comment: Using `display: table-cell;` on the fieldset fixes it for Firefox. But this breaks it for IE.

Comment: Also try `table-row`, `table-column` etc. works for Fx, not sure IE.

Comment: Guys see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408815/fieldset-resizes-wrong-appears-to-have-unremovable-min-width-min-content

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Which version of IE does it breaks? I cannot reproduce on IE on my end with both `min-width` and `display`

Comment: @Pangloss: Good job finding that gem. It also supports my observation of it breaking IE.

Comment: @Frederik.L IE 11.0.9600.18036. Reproduction: http://jsfiddle.net/kd9f23dp/ visual: http://screencast.com/t/y1uWjiGibX

Comment: OK, based on that excellent SO answer, I found a way to make it work in all browsers. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6tt1j4m/ @Frederik.L: If you update your answer with these details, I will accept it. Please also link to the other excellent answer

Comment: @Pangloss Good catch! Updated my answer with consideration of that fix.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Already did :D

Comment: Thanks guys, that was awesome! :-)

Comment: Cheers, have a good one.