# hide border if div is above

Tags: html, css, border

I have a `<div id="content">` with a border. Above this `div` is another `<div id="header">` with some text. I would like to show text over border, but i don't want to display it.

For easier explanation i've posted my source code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4HSEn/ and this is what i would like to achieve:

[image]

Text will be dynamic and background will be gradient. So image is not a solution.

I know how to achieve this with `fieldset` and `legend` tags, but i'm looking for a solution with div or any other tag.

found something here: [Is it possible to achieve a <fieldset>-like effect without using the <fieldset> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213881/is-it-possible-to-achieve-a-fieldset-like-effect-without-using-the-fieldset) but for the `legend` was used background-color:#FFF, which does not help me very much :/

Comment: btw. Gradient background is not supported by IE9 http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient ..So maybe you need to use images.

Comment: I know that IE does not support many good stuff.. i will use css3pie :)

Comment: Just curious, what's the problem with the fieldset/legend tags?

Comment: @j08691 If this is not really an actual fieldset, you'd be abusing the `fieldset` element for purposes it's not meant for!

Answer (score 2):

Untested theory, but perhaps you could give #header the same gradient background as body's background, then offset #header's background-position (using js) with the X and Y position relative to body?

Basically I'm suggesting a kind of masking effect.

EDIT: replaced #content with body, to be more in line with the OP's current code sample.

Comment: I actually came quite close to the solution with JS. But then I gave up. I've updated jsfiddle (url in the question) with script which calculates which color do i need. If i will have time, i will complete the script and post my solution. +1 for idea

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you push your content div up by setting the top position to a negative value:

`<div id="header" style="background-color: blue;">Demo</div>
<div id="content" style="top: -15px; border: 1px solid white"></div>`

Answer (score -1):

Enclose your text in a `<span style="background-color: blue;">` or something like that. That should work.

Comment: He's going for a gradient background. A solid background-color would stand out against it.