# Make text container to fit content automatically

Tags: css, alignment

I want to achieve this particular display by CSS:

[image]

I need to put there various texts and the lines to fill the white space that is left on right and left.

So far I got to this http://jsfiddle.net/g5jtm/, however there are several issues that I encounter:

1. the width of the text is variable and if I get out the `width:40%;` it will reset the width of the other 2 lines
2. The display:table does not allow me to align the lines through the middle of the text

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="lines l1"></div>
    <div class="copy">Consumer review</div>
    <div class="lines l2"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {width:100%; display:table; position:relative; height:100px;}
.lines, .copy  {display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:auto; }
.copy {  white-space: nowrap; padding:3px; text-align:center; font-size:24px; width:40%;}
.l1,.l2 {border-bottom:1px solid red; height:50px; }
```

Comment: I know this is not the question. But have you tried to use `<fieldset><legend>My Teyt</legend></fieldset>` for this effect?

Comment: Do you want the line to go behind the text?

Comment: @Paulie_D no ... that is the idea :)

Comment: @NicoO apparently I cannot achieve what I want using fieldset. Here is some explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213881/is-it-possible-to-achieve-a-fieldset-like-effect-without-using-the-fieldset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way with pseudo-elements

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FnvoH)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="line">Consumer Review</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.line {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.line:before,
.line:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9FD35F, #4F8C31) no-repeat center / 98% 3px;
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a horizontal line tag

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="lines l1"><hr></div>
<div class="copy">Consumer review</div>
<div class="lines l2"><hr></div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {width:100%; display:table; position:relative; height:100px;}
.lines, .copy  {display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:auto; }
.copy {  white-space: nowrap; padding:3px; text-align:center; font-size:24px; width:40%;}
hr {color:red}
```

Comment: You should post a fiddle of your answer.

Comment: Ok. Can you get rid of width:40%; in the "copy" CSS?