# Is it wrong to use the fieldset tag without form tag?

Tags: html, forms, fieldset

I was wondering if I can use the `fieldset` tag without being inside a `form`. Because I like the way it encloses the `legend` & the border stuff around the inner html. When I use it to enclose `li` element, it does behave like its actually there(visual) inside a form.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's valid HTML5. Paste the following HTML at the **validator: http://validator.w3.org/check**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    <fieldset> <legend>Test</legend> </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

It's also valid HTML4. Replace `<!DOCTYPE html>` with the following, and it still passes the validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use any form elements outside of an actual form, since most of them can be used with JavaScript utilities outside the form. The form is only needed if you plan on allowing the user to submit the data with it.

Answer (score 7):

One thing to keep in mind is that you should separate structure and design. Do you want a fieldset because it **is** a fieldset or because the fieldset **looks** nice?

See also:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/separationdilemma/
- https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html

Comment: I have flash graphs so I want them to be in some container which separates each graph. So Im using `fieldset` tag

Comment: If you want "some container", why don't you use a `div` - which is meant for that - and style it the way you want?

Comment: <div style="border: 1px solid grey; margin-bottom:40px; margin-top:40px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"> For me, it did the job, instead of fieldsets. Caring about the logic of your programming/layouting-language is not a bad thing!

Comment: I want it because it looks nice and reproducing it is [apparently hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213881/1026).

Comment: @Nickolay that's a real real bad practice. Semantics matter.